# Sql Azure geo-replication not replicating schema changes

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have created two blank sql azure database instances in 2 different regions and enabled geo-replication between them. I can failover between them no problem. I create the tables in the primary. I am expecting to see the schema changes replicated to the secondary, but this does not happen. Why not?

UPDATE:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.geo_replication_links
```

executed on primary master shows me the partner server and database

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_geo_replication_link_status
```

executed on primary master is empty

Answer (score 3):

It absolutely should happen. Any structural changes should be transmitted through Geo-Replication. The same as with data. If you're not seeing this, you may not have set up the geo-replication properly. Validate this is working by looking at [sys.geo_replication_links](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt575501.aspx). You can also look at [sys.dm_geo_replication_link_status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-geo-replication-link-status-azure-sql-database) to see if something has gone wrong. If everything is actually connected correctly and you're still not seeing the table changes replicated, you should contact support.

Comment: Actually this was my mistake, it was replicating to a different database to the one I expected. Thanks for your help